# Keep notification icon in the status bar when clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I want to display a simple notification when my app is running and doing certain things. I want my app to open when the user clicks my notification.
So far, the behaviour works like I want it to.
However, when the user clicks the notification, while the app is opened and the notification is still there, the notification icon in the notification bar (left to the time, before swiping down) disappears. Edit: I just observed that the notification icon reappears in the notification bar once any other notification (WhatsApp) arrives.
How can I prevent this behaviour?

The notification looks as following:

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    builder.setContentTitle("Running")
            .setContentText("App is running.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lock_outline_black_24dp)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(intent);
    notifyManager.notify(appRunningNotificationID, builder.build());
```

Comment: Have you tried `setAutoCancel(false)`?

Comment: @AlbAtNf Just tried, same behaviour. Figured the notification is not cancelled because it's still there, only the icon is gone. Just observed that icon reappears once any other notification (whatsapp) arrives.

Comment: Do you run stock android or any custom rom?

Comment: @AlbAtNf Running 6.0.1 stock (MMB29Q) on Nexus 6P.

Answer (score 0):

Look code below:

```
           TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Running")
                .setContentText("App is running")
                .setTicker("My app")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        long[] vibrate = { 500,1000 };
        notification.vibrate = vibrate;
        mNotificationManager.notify(appRunningNotificationID, notification);
```

Comment: You should use TaskStackBuilder

Comment: IllegalStateException: No intents added to TaskStackBuilder; cannot getPendingIntent.